# page going blank in react, from obtaining information about user in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So what I am first doing is obtaining the user and getting the user ID as such

```
 function GetCurrentUser() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                db.collection("users")
                    .doc(user.uid)
                    .get()
                    .then((snapshot) => {
                        setUser(user);
                    });
            } else {
                setUser(null);
            }
        });
    }, []);
    return user;
}


 function GetUserID() {
    const [uid, setUID] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                setUID(user.uid);
            }
        })
    }, [])
    return uid;
}
```

However now if I decide to print the UID it shows completely fine and perfect, however what I am trying to do is reach the user information ( like first name, last name, address ) to do that I do another function where I return only the snapshot.data() of the user.

```
function GetUserDetails() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                db.collection("users")
                    .doc(user.uid)
                    .get()
                    .then((snapshot) => {
                        setUser(snapshot.data());
                    });
            } else {
                setUser(null);
            }
        });
    }, []);
    return user;
}
```

However If i go now and try to show the details as such the page will go blank white and in the console the following error will show

```
   <tr>

        <td>
            {userDetails.Address}<br />
        </td>
        <td>
            {userDetails.FirstName + userDetails.LastName}<br />
            {userDetails.Email}
        </td>


  </tr>
```

> react-dom.development.js:11340 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Address')

What i noticed is that if i remove the part where i show userDetails.FirstName and those stuff everything will show properly, but when i put it back again it will actually work and the uid will be seen and information will be printed.

Summary : once i get navigated to this page my uid gets null and my page goes blank , however if i remove the part where i show userDetails.FirstName LastName and Address the page shows and it works properly. Moreover if i remove those information and put them back in, everything will work fine and uid will show and all the information will show, but teach time i navigate to the page it always shows blank.

I am not sure how to fix this, it feels like something very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means `userDetails` is `null` at the time you're trying to access `userDetails.Address`. Handle that case in your render function:

```
// assuming your component returns one row
// null can be returned from a render function and doesn't show up in the DOM
return userDetails && (
  <tr>
    <td>
      {userDetails.Address}<br />
    </td>
    <td>
      {userDetails.FirstName + userDetails.LastName}<br />
      {userDetails.Email}
    </td>
  </tr>
)
```

or render a placeholder

```
!userDetails
  ? <tr><td colSpan={2}>Fetching user data</td></tr>
  : <tr>
      <td>
        {userDetails.Address}<br />
      </td>
      <td>
        {userDetails.FirstName + userDetails.LastName}<br />
        {userDetails.Email}
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you so much! so to understand more what you did is we return userDetails only when its available however when its not it returns nothing but  does it like keep checking until we get a userDetails?

Comment: @OmarAssouma The right side of an `&&` expression is only evaluated and returned by the expression if the left side, `userDetail` in this case, is truthy, i.e. an object and not `null`. Otherwise, the left side is returned.
It doesn't "keep checking" but React re-renders the component when you update the state by calling `setUser`